# Kruskal-Wallis test for Length vs Year test

Tags: kruskal-wallis-test

I have a dataset of the lengths of a species which has a 1-year lifespan, going back 20 years. 
I would like to test if the lengths recorded each year are significantly different from one another (for each sex, we already know that there is a difference between the sexes).

My length data does not have a normal distribution; therefore, I was thinking of using the Kruskal-Wallis test.
However, I am not sure if that is the right way forward for the following reasons:

1) It requires an ordinal scale for the dependent variable, and I am unsure if this applies to length data

2) Is it okay that I am treating the years as a 'group' in this case? I would have ~20 groups.

3) Biologically speaking, I know that each year we are measuring different population, as this species spawns and dies (in a different location to where they are sampled) and the data is temporally independent. However, is there a way to prove this statistically? I attempted running the autocorrelation function in R but I am unsure if that is the way to go?

Many thanks!

Comment: How comes your lengths are not normally distributed? Because discrete ages?

Comment: @KaPy3141 Lengths will tend to be right skew. They certainly can't actually be normally distributed because lengths cannot be negative.

Comment: Lengths are ratio scale; Kruskal-Wallis should not have a problem (though personally I'd probably consider a generalized linear model). It's not clear that lengths are necessarily independent across years since the population in one year is descended from the population in the previous year.

Comment: @Glen_b: Thanks, I get it!

Comment: @Glen_b, thank you for the response, how would you suggest dealing with autocorrelation if I was to find that this is the case? Would a generalised least squares as described here - https://rpubs.com/markpayne/164550 applicable?

Comment: Would you be more interested in treating year as a continuous variable and looking for a trend over years?

Comment: @ichemshirova it depends; probably best to post a new question in that case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1): It doesn't need ordinal variables. Your R implementation automatically ranks your variables which makes them ordinal.

2): Yes, that's ok. Just be aware of additional biases than gender. (age distribution)

3) Yes, you can do a regression of your choice. For example linear regression to show that there is no linear time dependence.

(I am not a statistics expert myself, but I am quite confident this should be correct)

Comment: Could you explain how you're using linear regression to show there's no autocorrelation in "3)"?

Comment: I referred to the first part of the question: If there is a way to analyze temporal dependence. The answer is there are multiple ways. Just the result needs to be interpreted differently! (Linear for linear effect, auto-correlation for year-to-year effect)

Comment: @KaPy3141 Thanks for the info!